# What does the suffix on the end of glGetProgramiv signify?

Tags: opengl

[glGetProgramiv](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetProgram.xhtml) is referenced inside the documentation as glGetProgram but no mention is made of there being multiple versions - and I see no indication through google of there being other versions such as glGetProgrammiii or glGetProgramii. Is the iv prefix roman numerals related to some type of internal versioning during the specifications process or does it hold some other significance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Those suffixes are used to distinguish "overloaded" methods with same names and different parameters](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Nomenclature#Function_suffixes). `iv` means this version operates on vector of integers. It's the only version of `glGetProgram` at the moment.